# Updating last values of a group

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where I'm trying to replace NAs with values based on some conditions. For some reason, I'm getting more NAs.

Dataframe looks like this:

```
Employee.ID ta_start    prv_state   nxt_state   border_chk
33          10/24/2017  WYOMING     COLORADO    1
33          5/20/2019   WYOMING     NA          NA
19421       12/6/2019   TEXAS       TEXAS       NA
19421       12/17/2019  TEXAS       TEXAS       1
19421       1/6/2020    TEXAS       TEXAS       1
19421       1/30/2020   TEXAS       NA          NA
```

I want the output to be this:

```
Employee.ID ta_start    prv_state   nxt_state   border_chk
33          10/24/2017  WYOMING     COLORADO    1
33          5/20/2019   WYOMING     COLORADO    1
19421       12/6/2019   TEXAS       TEXAS       NA
19421       12/17/2019  TEXAS       TEXAS       1
19421       1/6/2020    TEXAS       TEXAS       1
19421       1/30/2020   TEXAS       TEXAS       1
```

This code I have is not getting the job done; it's replacing both target columns with a bunch of NAs:

```
ta_roll_up4a <- as.data.frame(ta_roll_up4 %>%
               group_by(Employee.ID) %>%
               arrange(ta_start) %>%
               dplyr::mutate(nxt_state = ifelse(nxt_state == dplyr::last(nxt_state), lag(nxt_state), nxt_state),
                             border_chk = ifelse(border_chk == dplyr::last(border_chk), 1, border_chk)) %>%
               arrange(Employee.ID, ta_start))
```

Wrong result I'm currently getting:

```
Employee.ID ta_start    prv_state   nxt_state   border_chk
33          10/24/2017  WYOMING     NA          NA
33          5/20/2019   WYOMING     NA          NA
19421       12/6/2019   TEXAS       NA          NA
19421       12/17/2019  TEXAS       NA          NA
19421       1/6/2020    TEXAS       NA          NA
19421       1/30/2020   TEXAS       NA          NA
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Update: I changed the ifelse from

```
mutate(nxt_state = ifelse(nxt_state = dplyr::last(nxt_state), lag(nxt_state), nxt_state), 
       border_chk = ifelse(border_chk = dplyr::last(border_chk), 1, border_chk))
```

to this to make them logical statements

```
mutate(nxt_state = ifelse(nxt_state == dplyr::last(nxt_state), lag(nxt_state), nxt_state), 
       border_chk = ifelse(border_chk == dplyr::last(border_chk), 1, border_chk))
```

Comment: In your. `ifelse` statement, the `test` is not logical `ifelse(dplyr::last(nxt_state)` insstead it. would be `ifelse(nxt_state == dplyr::last(nxt_state)`

Comment: That's it. Thanks akrun.

Comment: Spoke too soon. Even with the == fix, I'm still getting NAs.

Comment: I don't want to fill all of the NAs Akrun; only the ones that meet the conditions. Any reason why my original attempt is not working even after fixing = to ==?

Comment: The dates are set as dates in the main code. After sorting by date, I want to only change the NAs to the other value if it's the last item in the group; if it's not the last item in the group, I want to leave it alone. If the value is NA and it's not the last in the sorted group,  I want it to stay as an NA.

Comment: Does the updated solutions work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `group_by`  `Employee.ID` and replace `NA` value in last row with its previous value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Employee.ID) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(nxt_state, border_chk), 
            ~replace(., row_number() == n() & is.na(.), .[n() - 1]))

#  Employee.ID ta_start   prv_state nxt_state border_chk
#        <int> <fct>      <fct>     <fct>          <int>
#1          33 10/24/2017 WYOMING   COLORADO           1
#2          33 5/20/2019  WYOMING   COLORADO           1
#3       19421 12/6/2019  TEXAS     TEXAS             NA
#4       19421 12/17/2019 TEXAS     TEXAS              1
#5       19421 1/6/2020   TEXAS     TEXAS              1
#6       19421 1/30/2020  TEXAS     TEXAS              1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Employee.ID = c(33L, 33L, 19421L, 19421L, 19421L, 
19421L), ta_start = structure(c(3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("1/30/2020", 
"1/6/2020", "10/24/2017", "12/17/2019", "12/6/2019", "5/20/2019"
), class = "factor"), prv_state = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("TEXAS", "WYOMING"), class = "factor"), 
nxt_state = structure(c(1L,NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("COLORADO", "TEXAS"), 
class = "factor"), border_chk = c(1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak. This got me where I wanted to go.

Answer (score 0):

In the OP's code, the `ifelse` `test` is not logical  (according to `?ifelse` - test - an object which can be coerced to logical mode)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
```

Based on the OP's update to only replace the last NA elements, can create a. function to `replace only the last NA values with the previous non-NA

```
f1 <- function(x) {
      i1 <- cumsum(!is.na(x))
      i2 <- i1== max(i1)
      replace(x, which(i2)[-1], x[which(i2)[1]])
      }
ta_roll_up4 %>% 
   arrange(Employee.ID, mdy(ta_start)) %>%
   group_by(Employee.ID) %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(nxt_state, border_chk), f1)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   Employee.ID [2]
#  Employee.ID ta_start   prv_state nxt_state border_chk
#        <int> <chr>      <chr>     <chr>          <int>
#1          33 10/24/2017 WYOMING   COLORADO           1
#2          33 5/20/2019  WYOMING   COLORADO           1
#3       19421 12/6/2019  TEXAS     TEXAS              1
#4       19421 12/17/2019 TEXAS     TEXAS              1
#5       19421 1/6/2020   TEXAS     TEXAS              1
#6       19421 1/30/2020  TEXAS     TEXAS              1
```

---

Or use `na.locf` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
ta_roll_up4 %>%
  arrange(Employee.ID, mdy(ta_start)) %>%
  mutate(border_chk = replace(border_chk, 4, NA)) %>% # adding an NA in between
  group_by(Employee.ID) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(nxt_state, border_chk), ~ 
      case_when(row_number() >= last(which(!is.na(.))) ~ 
              na.locf0(.), TRUE ~ .))
```

#### data

```
ta_roll_up4 <- structure(list(Employee.ID = c(33L, 33L, 19421L, 19421L, 19421L, 
19421L), ta_start = c("10/24/2017", "5/20/2019", "12/6/2019", 
"12/17/2019", "1/6/2020", "1/30/2020"), prv_state = c("WYOMING", 
"WYOMING", "TEXAS", "TEXAS", "TEXAS", "TEXAS"), nxt_state = c("COLORADO", 
NA, "TEXAS", "TEXAS", "TEXAS", NA), border_chk = c(1L, NA, 1L, 
1L, 1L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: This would not work for me akrun; did not get desired output.

Comment: @wolf7687 based on the input i get the desired output